# How about expired time when a cache is hit in Memcache?

Tags: memcached

When I set a key in Memcache with specific expired time (for instance: 10 minutes)?
How about it after if I reach it?

> I expect that the expired time will be update 10 minutes again.

If not what is the solution to update expired time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All store operations take an expiration so you need to set it each time you do a store operation.

If you are using the latest version of memcached then you will have the option of doing touch and gat (get and touch) commands. touch will allow you to just reset the expiration of a key and gat will allow you to get a key and reset the expiration. In both cases though you must specify the new expiration time since memcached will not remember it.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize count of touch() operations, you can save expiration time in 'flag' variable, if API of your module allows this.

According to https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt flags are saved via SET operation

```
 set <key> <flags> <exptime> <bytes> [noreply]\r\n
```

and could be got by GET operation:

```
 get <key>*\r\n

 Each item sent by the server looks like this:

 VALUE <key> <flags> <bytes> [<cas unique>]\r\n <data block>\r\n
```

I.e. you get FLAGS any time you doing GET anyway of you want )
So my proposal is to use FLAGS to check if expiration time is far enough, and do TOUCH only if really needed, not each time when doing GET.

In such scheme, you can`t do TOUCH anymore (because this not shift expiration time stored in flags) but should use CAS to set new VALUE and FLAGS both.

Please note, what most of time high-level libraries (perl,php, etc) uses FLAGS to own needs, for example to save flags whether data was comressed, serialized, converted from UTF-8 and so on, so you can use flags only for simple data (not compressed and not serialized by your library).